# How to find the discontinuous feature based on its attribute in Arcmap by using python

Tags: python, dictionary, arcpy

I am very beginning in Python.
I have an electrical network with a large attribute table. Here I posted only a small part of the network.
The image of the network is given below.
**Arcpy**
[In the image shows the error of the discontinuous feature by color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsYOK.jpg)

I want to do these things below:

1. This is the LINE features, where one ending vertex is the starting vertex of another line.
2. Lines must be adjacent to the same value of q50 field. It should not be discrete.
3. If any line is discrete the Status Field will show FALSE. Otherwise, it is TRUE.

My First Attempt:

I made a dictionary

```
Dicts = {}
```

so that I can use in the Loop. I don’t know it is applicable or not.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"G:\1. DESCO\2. SND\DESCO_GIS.mdb"
Table = r"G:\1. DESCO\2. SND\DESCO_GIS.mdb\SNDLT"
Output = r"G:\1. DESCO\2. SND\DESCO_GIS.mdb\SNDLT_Disslove"
Dicts = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Table, ["OID", "q50"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        key = row[0]
        value = row [1]
        if not key in Dicts:
            Dicts[key] = [value]
upCur = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Table, ["q50", "Status"])
for row in upCur:
```

My Second Attempts:

I Dissolve the Layer based on q50 Field.

```
arcpy.Dissolve_management(Table, Output, "q50", " ", " ", " ")
```

My expected output:

```
OID Shape_Length    q50 Status
1   34.042799   KB_45   TRUE
2   29.433213   KB_45   TRUE
3   28.935468   KB_40   FALSE
4   28.098186   KB_45   TRUE
5   17.087751   KB_45   TRUE
6   24.486309   KB_30   TRUE
7   10.6042869  KB_30   TRUE
8   27.879100   KB_30   FALSE
9   30.116200   KB_40   TRUE
10  26.952097   KB_40   TRUE
11  30.398597   KB_40   TRUE
```

I tried but I can't identify the discontinuous features.